# AVR project 32x40 pixel screen

Tags: c++, avr

I have now for some time been building a 32x40 pixel screen that I'm writing some code to operate. So far I have managed to make the code take a class that I have made (a bit map for all pixels) and used it to make a pixel turn on which I then have been able to move around with a controller.

```
class display{
public:
    display(){
      for (uint8_t y = 0;y<40; y++){ 
        for(uint8_t x = 0; x<32;x++) {
            matrix[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }
    void set_pixel(uint8_t x, uint8_t y){
        if(x<32 && y<40) matrix[x/8][y] |= (1<<(x%8));
    }
    uint8_t get_pixel(uint8_t x, uint8_t y){
        if(x<32 && y<40){
            return (matrix[x/8][y]&(1<<x%8))>0 ? 1:0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
private:
    uint8_t matrix[4][40];
};
```

Because i need to save some space, I can't use a uint_8 [3][3]; array to display a 3x3 pixel picture; and have instead tried to make an other class of varying size:

```
class Image{
public:
    Image(uint8_t size_x,uint8_t size_y): Length_y(size_y), Length_x(size_x), x_bytes((size_x+7)/8){
        matrix = (uint8_t*) malloc(size_y*x_bytes); //malloc replaces the new operator
    void set_pixel(uint8_t x, uint8_t y){
        if(!OutOfRangeException(x,y)) matrix[x_bytes*y-(x/8)] |= (1<<(x%8));
    }
    bool get_pixel(uint8_t x,uint8_t y){
        if(OutOfRangeException(x,y)) return 0;
        return (matrix[x_bytes*y-(x/8)] & (1<<(x%8))) >0 ? 1:0;
    }
    void clear_pixel(uint8_t x,uint8_t y){
        if(!OutOfRangeException(x,y)) matrix[x_bytes*y-(x/8)] |= (1<<(x%8));
    }
    const uint8_t Length_y;
    const uint8_t Length_x;
private:
    uint8_t OutOfRangeException(uint8_t x, uint8_t y){
        if( x >= this->Length_x || y >= this->Length_y) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    uint8_t *matrix;
    uint8_t x_bytes;    
};
```

The Classes seem to work fine when I use them independently where the following code:

```
Image img(3,3);
img.set_pixel(0,0);
for (uint8_t y = 0;y<3; y++){
    for(uint8_t x = 0; x<3 ;x++) {
        SendNumber(img.get_pixel(x,y));
    }
}
```

Produces this on my serial monitor:

1,0,0,
0,0,0,
0,0,0,

But here comes the problem when i try to use the image bitmap to move a pixel to the display nothing happens:

```
if(img.get_pixel(0,0)) USART_send('T'); // the Char T is sent to the serial monitor    
display Screen;
if(img.get_pixel(0,0)) Screen.set_pixel(10,10); // a pixel is not set
if(1) Screen.set_pixel(15,15);                  // a pixel is set
```

from the data i get from my serial monitor i can see that img.get_pixel(0,0) should evaluate true. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong. I'm running this code on a ATmega328P (arduino nano) and I'm programming in atmel studio 6.2

Comment: Look at `std::vector` and replace large parts of your code with it. Also, look at C++ cast operators and stop using C-style casts. Lastly, please extract a minimal but complete example representing your problem, not some random parts of your whole project.

Comment: Would have loved to use vectors but vector library is not supported for AVR programming. My problems lies in the 3 last line of code where the screen.set_pixel(10,10) won't set the pixel in my map. I only recently started to use c++ so may i ask what is the difference between c++cast c-style cast?

Comment: A `uint_8 [3][3];` array takes up 9 bytes of memory. Your 3x3 `Image` object takes up at least 10 bytes of memory. That's 5 bytes for the class members, 3 for the `matrix` array and a least 2 more bytes for allocator overhead. That doesn't count all the additional program memory needed for all the code needed to implement the class.

Comment: hmm That is quite usefull knowladge thanks.

Comment: Make sure you `free` the `malloc`ed memory in a destructor.

Comment: Yeah was going to do that as soon as i got the code up and working

Comment: Okay so while looking over the code with my friend i found that the constructor for the display class is running wilde defining a 32x40 array instead of a 4x40 array. Which are a reminder of an old system i was using